# Pandas: Merged data creates object type when used

Tags: python, pandas

I'm sure I'm just missing something here but I can't find it.

have merged 2 dataframes with left join. works as I expected until I attempt to use the generated value in a simple string concatenation.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import os
import numpy as np
import timeit

start_time = timeit.default_timer()

file_count = 1
data_df_left = {'name': ['Jack','Jill','Jenny','Ben','Lee','Kate','John','Amy','Darren','Paul'],
                'classroom': ['150F','200F','250F','150F','350F','150F','350F','450F','450F','500F'],
                'teacher': ['Jackson','Bird','McKay','Jackson','Yule','Jackson','Yule','Summers','Summers','Young']}

data_df_right = {'class_id': ['150F','200F','250F','300F','350F','375F','400F','425F','450F','500F'],
                 'classroom_sq_ft': [81.05,73.68, 89.47,75.79,86.32,78.95,73.68,80,74.74,73.68]}



left_df = pd.DataFrame(data_df_left)
right_df = pd.DataFrame(data_df_right)

left_df = pd.merge(left_df,distance_df,left_on='classroom',right_on='class_id', how='left')



left_df['classroom_detail'] = str(left_df.classroom) + ":" + str(left_df.classroom_sq_ft)

print left_df.classroom
print left_df.classroom_sq_ft
print left_df.classroom_detail
```

OUTPUT:

```
0    150F
1    200F
2    250F
3    150F
4    350F
5    150F
6    350F
7    450F
8    450F
9    500F
Name: classroom, dtype: object
0    90.53
1    93.68
2    78.95
3    90.53
4    82.11
5    90.53
6    82.11
7    94.74
8    94.74
9    88.42
Name: classroom_sq_ft, dtype: float64
0    0    150F\n1    200F\n2    250F\n3    150F\n4 ...
1    0    150F\n1    200F\n2    250F\n3    150F\n4 ...
2    0    150F\n1    200F\n2    250F\n3    150F\n4 ...
3    0    150F\n1    200F\n2    250F\n3    150F\n4 ...
4    0    150F\n1    200F\n2    250F\n3    150F\n4 ...
5    0    150F\n1    200F\n2    250F\n3    150F\n4 ...
6    0    150F\n1    200F\n2    250F\n3    150F\n4 ...
7    0    150F\n1    200F\n2    250F\n3    150F\n4 ...
8    0    150F\n1    200F\n2    250F\n3    150F\n4 ...
9    0    150F\n1    200F\n2    250F\n3    150F\n4 ...
Name: classroom_detail, dtype: object
```

was really expecting an output somthing similar to:

```
0 150F:90.53
1 200F:93.68
...
```

Thanks in advance for the help !

Comment: check what `str(left_df.classroom)` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `astype(str)` to convert the floats to strings:

```
left_df['classroom_detail'] = (left_df['classroom'] + ':' 
                               + left_df['classroom_sq_ft'].astype(str))
```

You can add string-valued Series with other string-valued Series or with plain strings. The result is row-by-row concatenation.

---

```
In [115]: left_df['classroom'] + ':' + left_df['classroom_sq_ft'].astype(str)
Out[115]: 
0    150F:81.05
1    200F:73.68
2    250F:89.47
3    150F:81.05
4    350F:86.32
5    150F:81.05
6    350F:86.32
7    450F:74.74
8    450F:74.74
9    500F:73.68
dtype: object
```

---

`str(left_df['classroom'])` returns a string representation for the Series:

```
In [116]: str(left_df['classroom'])
Out[116]: '0    150F\n1    200F\n2    250F\n3    150F\n4    350F\n5    150F\n6    350F\n7    450F\n8    450F\n9    500F\nName: classroom, dtype: object'
```

whereas `astype(str)` converts the values in the Series into strings:

```
In [119]: list(left_df['classroom_sq_ft'].astype(str))
Out[119]: 
['81.05',
 '73.68',
 '89.47',
 '81.05',
 '86.32',
 '81.05',
 '86.32',
 '74.74',
 '74.74',
 '73.68']
```

Comment: Ah thank you ... When I first looked at your solution I thought "surely I've tried that" .... but no .... thanks again much appreciated.